# Cross-Thread Exceptions in Asynchronous Programming

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

In synchronous programming (before `async/await` arrived on the scene) it was clear to me how or why cross-thread exceptions occurred. If I launched a background thread to do some heavy task so as to offload UI thread and make it responsive, I knew exactly what to do to access UI thread from the background thread. If in doubt I could even check in what thread a given code was executing.

With async/await asynchronous programming, I find what was a clear-cut identification of threads somehow blurred and murky (even well demonstrated in debugging with call stacks jumping all over the place based on numerous awaited tasks).

What I try to find out is a kind of *roadmap* that would help me identify cross-thread danger areas/pitfalls along the bumpy async/await meander (forgive the metaphor).

What, exactly, would I be watching for to avoid cross-thread exceptions when it comes to asynchronous programming? Can these be made into some kind of checklist?

Comment: [mcve]; [faq]; and [ask]

Comment: If you're using the `async` keyword in a method that should run in the background and `await`ing the result, you'll need to `Invoke()` operations on the UI thread. Pretty much the same as before async/await.

Comment: @Micky: To me this is a clear question and for you to view it otherwise, in my defence, is a matter of opinion. What is the metric for this to qualify or fail as a proper question?

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_.  You said _"What I try to find out is a kind of **roadmap**"_ which is another way of saying guide or tutorial.  [roadmap (n)](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/road%20map). There's the metric.  It's my opinion that your question is off-topic.  Reword it to improve it.  Good luck!

Comment: I will say this, `async/await` if done properly, generally avoids cross-thread-GUI issues more so than spinning up a worker thread on your own in an attempt to update the UI later (via marshalling).  `async/await` is also a lot easier; less verbose.  Less code generally means less bugs.  Want to avoid such exceptions? Then using `async/await` is a good start

Comment: @E.Moffat If you're using 'invoke' in a modern app you're probably doing it wrong.  Awaiting marshals to the current context for you.

Comment: @Micky - On reflection I get your point and sorry for my question lacking the specificity it requires. Thank you for your honest comments, you're right. Thank you to all who jumped in with useful comments to my benefit. Stephen Cleary - thanks ever so much for being an evangelist/authority on asynchronous programming and for always being readily available to help. I just bought your book on Amazon and reading it with great interest. Thank you all!

Comment: @user2921851 No problem, we're all trying to help. :)  Agree about Stephen, his site and book are awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cover the main threading considerations in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). To be specific, the default behavior of `await` is to capture a "context" and then resume the method within that "context". In the case of a UI thread, that context will cause the `async` method to resume on the UI thread.

So, plain `async` and `await` simply avoid most cross-threading concerns completely.

Note that if you do introduce background threads (e.g., `Task.Run`), then of course those background threads can cause cross-threading exceptions and you'll have to avoid those appropriately.

Comment: Someone down-voted Stephen? That's just bizarre.  My +1 is in there in any case :)

Comment: If someone down-voted Stephen it must be a mistake. I just tried to up-vote but my limited reputation, further dented by my question, (below the requisite 15 to vote) didn't allow me. Yes, it would be bizarre to down-vote Stephen and hope it was just a genuine mishap.